# How to intersect and combine multiple object arrays using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to find the intersection between n >=2 object arrays which share the same key while also combining the object arrays. I'm looking for the most efficient way to do this. The max length of any of the arrays would be around ~2500 objects long.

An example of what I'm looking for :

```
object1 = [
  {
    key: 'key1',
    x: 'x',
    y: 'y',
    z: 'z'
  },
  {
    key: 'key2',
    x: 'x',
    y: 'y',
    z: 'z'
  }
]

object2 = [
  {
    key: 'key1',
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b'
  },
  {
    key: 'key3',
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b'
  }
]

object3 = [
  {
    key: 'key1',
    c: 'c'
  },
  {
    key: 'key4',
    c: 'c'
  }
]
```

with the desired output :

```
object = [
  {
    key: 'key1',
    x: 'x',
    y: 'y',
    z: 'z',
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b',
    c: 'c'
  }
]
```

To combine two object arrays, I've used the following function :

```
    let map = new Map(object1.map(o => [o['key'], o]));
    return object2.reduce((acc, o) => {
        let match = map.get(o['key']);
        return match ? acc.concat({ ...o, ...match }) : acc;
    }, []);
```

But I'm not sure how to apply this to more arrays in a way that's not resource and time heavy. Any tips would be appreciated. I'm also open for using helper functions like underscore or lodash.

Comment: This question isn't good fit for SO, you should ask it in [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: alex - the main difference between your code and mine is mine takes all the onerous key matching out of the reduce by filtering for potential intersections first. Filtering out non-matching keys before trying to assemble the finished array should save on processing. I'd be interested to learn if this is the case with your data.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage (i hope) with this code is that it will preprocess all objects first to find intersecting keys before attempting to reduce and combine each one. In the first iteration `fkeys` flattens all objects together so we can do just one loop.

Separating those 2 processes should reduce overhead. My guess though is that there's a more elegant way to do this. I added in another intersecting key (key2) for demonstration in snippet

```
let objs = [object1, object2, object3],
  fkeys = Object.keys(Object.fromEntries(Object.entries([...objs.flat()].map(o => o.key).reduce((b, a) => {
    if (b.hasOwnProperty(a)) b[a] = b[a] + 1;
    else b[a] = 1;
    return b
  }, {})).filter(k => k[1] === objs.length))),
  intersections = Object.values([...objs.flat()].filter(o => fkeys.includes(o.key)).reduce((b, a) => {
    if (b.hasOwnProperty(a.key)) b[a.key] = { ...b[a.key], ...a};
    else b[a.key] = { ...a};
    return b}, {}))
```

```js
object1 = [{
    key: 'key1',
    x: 'x',
    y: 'y',
    z: 'z'
  },
  {
    key: 'key2',
    g: 'g',
    h: 'h',
    j: 'j'
  }
]

object2 = [{
    key: 'key1',
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b'
  },
  {
    key: 'key2',
    y: 'y',
    z: 'z'
  },
  {
    key: 'key3',
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b'
  }
]

object3 = [{
    key: 'key1',
    c: 'c'
  },
  {
    key: 'key2',
    r: 'r'
  },
  {
    key: 'key4',
    c: 'c'
  }
]

let objs = [object1, object2, object3],
  fkeys = Object.keys(Object.fromEntries(Object.entries([...objs.flat()].map(o => o.key).reduce((b, a) => {
    if (b.hasOwnProperty(a)) b[a] = b[a] + 1;
    else b[a] = 1;
    return b
  }, {})).filter(k => k[1] === objs.length))),
  intersections = Object.values([...objs.flat()].filter(o => fkeys.includes(o.key)).reduce((b, a) => {

    if (b.hasOwnProperty(a.key)) b[a.key] = { ...b[a.key],
      ...a
    };
    else b[a.key] = { ...a
    };
    return b;
  }, {}))



console.log(fkeys)
console.log(intersections)
```